# Error in find highest value

Tags: java, arrays

I wrote the following code to find the highest value in an array. It results in an `NullPointerException`. What is the problem?

```
double max;
max = student[0].getGrade();
for (int m=0; m<student.length;m++) 
{
  if (student[m] != null && student[m].getGrade() > max) 
  {
    max = student[m].getGrade();
  }
}
```

Comment: `cant run it` What does that mean ? Do you get an error ? Is it just not working ? Edit your post and add a precise question.

Comment: Saying you get a `a error Nullpointerexception` is not precise. Do you know what debugging is btw ?

Comment: @UDKOX  I try in many way and it doesnt work

Comment: Oh! Really ? What ways, what did you see ? We are not your employess. We are not here to do your work. We are here to help you with your problem, since you don't know what your proble, is, we can't help you.

Comment: You did not even check `(student != null)` or `(student[0] != null)` in your second line. Go learn some basics of Java.

Comment: In your 2nd line you are not checking if student[0] is null like you are in line 5. You are assuming there is a value in student[0].

Comment: @GeekyDaddy thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a student at index 0 of the student array

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
for (int m = 0; m < student.length; m++) 
{
    if (student[m].getGrade() > max) 
    {
          max = student[m].getGrade();
    }
}
```

If you add `student[m] != null &&` to the if statement then it fails as double cannot be null, and you cannot call a double if it was never given data.